# Multiple select user name SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

Hi I have 3 table that I want to join

Table Export

```
id | id_product | id_user  | id_loan
1  |     516    |    10    |    1
```

Table User

```
id |    Name    |
 5 |    John    |
10 |    Justin  |
```

Table Loan

```
id |   id_user  | Quantity |
 1 |     5      |    23    |
```

My sql code is

```
Select *
From Export
join User ON Export.id_user = User.id
join Loan ON Export.id_loan = Loan.id
```

How can I select that my result will be

```
ID Product | Export User | Loan User | Quantity
   516     |    Justin   |   John    |    23
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join with multiple instance of user

```
Select id_product,User.name as exportUser,u1.name as loanUser,quantity
From Export
left join User ON Export.id_user = User.id
left join Loan ON Export.id_loan = Loan.id
left join user u1 on Export.id_loan=u1.id
```

Comment: Thanks you this fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need one more `join`:

```
Select e.id_product, u.name as export_user, ul.name as loan_user, l.quantity
From Export e join
     User u
     on e.id_user = u.id join
     Loan l
     on e.id_loan = l.id join
     User ul
     on l.id_user = ul.id;
```

Note that if either of the users could be `null`, you probably want `left join`s:

```
Select e.id_product, u.name as export_user, ul.name as loan_user, l.quantity
From Export e left join
     User u
     on e.id_user = u.id left join
     Loan l
     on e.id_loan = l.id left join
     User ul
     on l.id_user = ul.id;
```

This will keep all rows in `export`, even when there are not matches in the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need  the table use two time with proper table name alias

```
  Select Export.id_product, a.name esport_user, b.name loan_user, Loan.quantity 
  From Export
  join User a ON Export.id_user = User.id
  join User b ON Export.id_loan = User.id
  join Loan ON Export.id_loan = Loan.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` to the tables appropriately to get the result you want:

```
SELECT  e.id_product AS `ID Product`,
        ue.Name AS `Export User`,
        ul.Name AS `Loan User`,
        l.quantity
  FROM  Export e
    LEFT JOIN User ue ON ue.id = e.id_user
    LEFT JOIN Loan l ON l.id = e.id_loan
    LEFT JOIN User ul ON ul.id = l.id_user
```

The first `JOIN` to the `User` table gets the export user (as `ue`) and the second gets the loan user (as `ul`).

Output:

```
ID Product  Export User   Loan User     quantity
516         Justin        John          23
```

A working fiddle showing this in action is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08d64b/1).